# Shell script works manually but doesn't work correctly in Crontab

Tags: command-line, bash, pulseaudio, cron, ffmpeg

I have a Python script to record audio/video using the "subprocess" module to execute ffmpeg commands, as follows:

```
def kill_ffmpeg_process(args):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name', 'cmdline']):
        if proc.info['name'] == 'ffmpeg' and args in proc.info['cmdline']:
            print("found: " + str(proc))
            proc.kill()

kill_ffmpeg_process("ffmpeg")

rand_num = str(random.randint(0,99))
record_internal_cmd = f"ffmpeg -f pulse -ac 2 -i 'alsa_input.pci-0000_00_05.0.analog-stereo' -f v4l2 -i /dev/video4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 Desktop/recordings/{get_today_timestamp()}_{str(rand_num)}_internal_feed.mkv"
record_external_cmd = f"ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video5 Desktop/recordings/{get_today_timestamp()}_{str(rand_num)}_external_feed.mkv"

print("Recording /dev/video4 with audio")
subprocess.Popen(record_internal_cmd,shell=True,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(1)
print("Recording /dev/video5")
subprocess.Popen(record_external_cmd,shell=True,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(3)
```

I want to schedule this script to be executed every 1 hour (automatically) with crontab, so I created a .sh file that calls the Python script `#!/bin/bash python3 script.py`.
when executing it manually in terminal `./shell_script.sh` it works fine, but when adding it to a crontab it doesn't work because it cannot find the audio source "personal thoughts" because when I remove audio recording from it, it works.
But pulse audio recording doesn't work; it only executes the second command and creates the file that includes video recording.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with paths, because it's working as expected, except for the audio record part that can be found in "record_internal_cmd" it ignores it and executes "record_external_cmd"

Comment: Still, `ffmpeg` may not be found in a cronjob because conjobs have a very limited environment, so even PATH may not be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why is this happening?

Your script obviously needs Pulse Audio running ... Pulse audio is run(*automatically*) as a user service ... You can see the service's status with:

```
$ systemctl --user status pulseaudio
● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-04-25 14:26:50 +03; 13min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket
   Main PID: 120691 (pulseaudio)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 23594)
     Memory: 7.3M
        CPU: 389ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pulseaudio.service
             └─120691 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal

Apr 25 14:26:50 Lenovo systemd[5211]: Starting Sound Service...
Apr 25 14:26:50 Lenovo systemd[5211]: Started Sound Service.
```

The service unit itself can be inspected with:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service
[Unit]
Description=Sound Service

# We require pulseaudio.socket to be active before starting the daemon, because
# while it is possible to use the service without the socket, it is not clear
# why it would be desirable.
#
# A user installing pulseaudio and doing `systemctl --user start pulseaudio`
# will not get the socket started, which might be confusing and problematic if
# the server is to be restarted later on, as the client autospawn feature
# might kick in. Also, a start of the socket unit will fail, adding to the
# confusion.
#
# After=pulseaudio.socket is not needed, as it is already implicit in the
# socket-service relationship, see systemd.socket(5).
Requires=pulseaudio.socket
ConditionUser=!root

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
LockPersonality=yes
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
NoNewPrivileges=yes
Restart=on-failure
RestrictNamespaces=yes
SystemCallArchitectures=native
SystemCallFilter=@system-service
# Note that notify will only work if --daemonize=no
Type=notify
UMask=0077
Slice=session.slice

[Install]
Also=pulseaudio.socket
WantedBy=default.target
```

To see three important settings:

1. `WantedBy=default.target` which means the service won't necessarily be available until just before `default.target`(*the last multi-user enabled interface in the boot process*).
2. `Requires=pulseaudio.socket` which is only available after a user session has been started (*i.e. after login*)
3. `ConditionUser=!root` which means the user cannot be `root`.

Both the above **1** and **2** conditions work against the availability of a running Pulse Audio daemon for a crontab job during boot and before login.

Condition **3**, however, will not allow running a Pulse Audio daemon under `root` even after login.

#### What to do about it?

- You can add your cron job in your user's crontab(*Not `root`'s crontab*) and ensure your user is logged in when the cron job runs.
- You can manually run a Pulse Audio daemon in your script running your script as a certain user that you explicitly specify and in this case, even `root` can be used ... compare for example:

  ```
  $ sudo su root -c 'pacmd list-sources'
  No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
  ```

  Versus:

  ```
  $ sudo su root -c 'pulseaudio --start; pacmd list-sources'
  W: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).
  2 source(s) available.
       index: 0
       name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor>
       driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
       flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
       state: IDLE
       suspend cause: (none)
       priority: 1030
       volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
               balance 0.00
       base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
       volume steps: 65537
       muted: no
       current latency: 0.00 ms
       max rewind: 344 KiB
       sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
       channel map: front-left,front-right
                    Stereo
       used by: 0
       linked by: 0
       configured latency: 2000.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
       monitor_of: 0
       card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
       module: 7
       properties:
           device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo"
           device.class = "monitor"
           alsa.card = "0"
           alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
           alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xa12a8000 irq 136"
           alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
           device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
           sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
           device.bus = "pci"
           device.vendor.id = "8086"
           device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
           device.product.id = "9d71"
           device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio"
           device.form_factor = "internal"
           device.string = "0"
           module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
           device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
     * index: 1
       name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
       driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
       flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
       state: IDLE
       suspend cause: (none)
       priority: 9039
       volume: front-left: 3381 /   5% / -77.25 dB,   front-right: 3381 /   5% / -77.25 dB
               balance 0.00
       base volume: 6554 /  10% / -60.00 dB
       volume steps: 65537
       muted: yes
       current latency: 353.71 ms
       max rewind: 0 KiB
       sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
       channel map: front-left,front-right
                    Stereo
       used by: 0
       linked by: 0
       configured latency: 2000.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
       card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
       module: 7
       properties:
           alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
           device.api = "alsa"
           device.class = "sound"
           alsa.class = "generic"
           alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
           alsa.name = "ALC236 Analog"
           alsa.id = "ALC236 Analog"
           alsa.subdevice = "0"
           alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
           alsa.device = "0"
           alsa.card = "0"
           alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
           alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xa12a8000 irq 136"
           alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
           device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
           sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
           device.bus = "pci"
           device.vendor.id = "8086"
           device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
           device.product.id = "9d71"
           device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio"
           device.form_factor = "internal"
           device.string = "front:0"
           device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
           device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
           device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
           device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
           device.profile.description = "Analogue Stereo"
           device.description = "Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo"
           module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
           device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
       ports:
           analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
               properties:
                   device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
           analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
               properties:
                   device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
       active port: <analog-input-internal-mic>
  ```
- You can [run Pulse Audio as system-wide daemon](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/SystemWide/).

Comment: Thank you for all that info, makes much more sense right now. 
actually, it was solved by adding a few more lines to my .sh script.
based on: [ffmpeg returns "no such process" error when called by cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68069727/ffmpeg-returns-no-such-process-error-when-called-by-cron)

Comment: @EliasTommeh You’re welcome … Glad that solved it … However, you might need to pay attention that [PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH](https://pulseaudio-discuss.freedesktop.narkive.com/LE8XtC9t/patch-don-t-let-user-set-pulse-runtime-path-values-affect-behaviour) might be deprecated soon … In case it stops working in the future.