# Automatically input text ( sript ) when the terminal open

Tags: scripts, pulseaudio, cron, sh

I have script to mute sound:

```
pactl set-sink-mute 0 true
```

Tt's working if I run directly in terminal but if I make `file.sh` or run in `crontab`:

```
* * * * * pactl set-sink-mute 0 true
```

I get error.

Is there any way if I open the terminal & the script auto write & auto enter in terminal by `file.sh` or `crontab`?

Regards,
Adrian

Comment: Related: [Shell script works manually but doesn't work correctly in Crontab](https://askubuntu.com/q/1465163)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell script works manually but doesn't work correctly in Crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465163/shell-script-works-manually-but-doesnt-work-correctly-in-crontab)