# How to execute command as "non_root" user in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, 22.04

When logging into the Ubuntu system, the login user is "`root`".

**And then, I want to execute some bash script on behalf of the "`non_root`":**

```
root@test_pc:~# echo $USER
root
root@test_pc:~# sudo -E -u non_root -g non_root -H /bin/bash -c "echo $USER"
root
root@test_pc:~#
```

But the output is still "`root`", in other words, the command is still execute under "`root`" user instead of "`non_root`".

**Here is the expected output:**

```
root@test_pc:~# sudo -E -u non_root -g non_root -H /bin/bash -c "echo $USER"
non_root
root@test_pc:~#
```

**Here is the real operation:**

```
sudo -E -u non_root -g non_root -H /bin/bash -c "systemctl --user disable pulseaudio.service"
```

**But got the following error:**

```
Failed to connect to bus: Operation not permitted (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)
```

How to execute any bash command as "`non_root`" when logged in with "`root`" user?

Comment: The big question is: Why are you logging in as `root`? This practice is generally discouraged, and you should instead login as a normal user, and use `sudo` to execute commands as `root`.

Comment: Because root has the highest privileges.

Comment: Maybe you don't understand the principle - but you should do it the other way around.

Comment: Double quotes allow for parameter expansion in the current shell on the current command line before the command gets executed … To expand $USER in the sub-shell instead use single quotes around the command string  instead … And pulseaudio is a user service that requires user login to run.

Comment: Short answer: don't log in as root. You are making it difficult for yourself for no reason. Instead, examine why you think you need to do it, and ask about the correct way to do whatever that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Needless to say that what you're doing i.e. logging in as the user `root` is discouraged and therefore the `root` user is disabled by default on Ubuntu.

That said, ...

Double quotes around the Bash command string allow for parameter expansion in the current shell on the current command line before the command gets executed … see it in action:

```
root@Lenovo:~# whoami
root
root@Lenovo:~# set -x
root@Lenovo:~# sudo -E -u ubuntu -g ubuntu -H /bin/bash -c "echo $USER"
+ sudo -E -u ubuntu -g ubuntu -H /bin/bash -c 'echo root'
root
```

While your command is actually executed as the intended user:

```
root@Lenovo:~# sudo -E -u ubuntu -g ubuntu -H /bin/bash -c "whoami"
ubuntu
```

To expand `$USER` in the sub-shell created to run that Bash command string instead use single quotes around the command string instead:

```
root@Lenovo:~# sudo -E -u ubuntu -g ubuntu -H /bin/bash -c 'echo $USER'
ubuntu
```

Notice as well that pulseaudio is a user service that requires user login to run ... See for example https://askubuntu.com/a/1465201 and Dbus is also part of the user’s user-runtime environment and requires a user login as well ... See for example https://askubuntu.com/a/1470118